# Array of string in C, strange behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm tryng to solve a puzzle on codegaming.
This is the simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void) {
    char *hashTable[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        char EXT[101]; 
        char MT[501];
        scanf("%s%s", EXT, MT); fgetc(stdin);
        hashTable[i]= MT;
    }
    printf("%s\n",hashTable[0]);
    printf("%s\n",hashTable[1]);
    printf("%s\n",hashTable[2]);
}
```

If for example I type: a a \n b b \n c c\n
The output will be: "c c c" instead of "a b c".  Why the last value "c" overwrite hashTable[0] and hashTable[1].
With the following code instead I received the correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void) {
    char *hashTable[3];
    char *hashTable2[3];
    hashTable2[0]="a";
    hashTable2[1]="b";
    hashTable2[2]="c";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        hashTable[i]= hashTable2[i];
    }
    printf("%s ",hashTable[0]);
    printf("%s ",hashTable[1]);
    printf("%s ",hashTable[2]);
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile: `hashTable[hashFunction(EXT,N)],MT, hashTable[0]);`?

Comment: Can you provide us some [MCVE]?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How is `hashFunction` defined and what kind of macro is that?! It must be defined like `#define hashFunction(a,b)  0], (""[0` to make this code at least compile.

Comment: `hashTable[i]= MT;` is a problem: `MT` value does not change in the `for` loop, so `hashTable[0,1 and 2]` will have the same value, which points to the last value stored in `MT`: `c`

Comment: You need to understand the code, not post "it does not work, help me". Read about [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). What storage duration does MT has? Read about [pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm). What does the line `hashTable[i] = MT;` do? Is `strcpy(hashtable[i], MT)` any different? Stackoverflow is not a learning site, you can find [much help on the net](https://tech.io/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-copy).

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `EXT` & `MT` are local in the `for` loop scope and they do not exists outside that scope. It is an UB.

Secondly you assign the same array address to all elements of your `char *` array. When you exit the loop this address is not valid anymore.

you need to allocate memory for all elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    hashTable[i]= malloc( /*some size*/);
    if(hashTable[i])
        scanf("%s", hashTable[i]); /* just an example */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays `EXT` and `MT` are local to the `for` containing block; they cease to exist at the terminating `}`.

Inside the block you put their address in `hashtable`.

When you try to print their contents (remember by this time the arrays ceased to exist) you invoke **Undefined Behaviour**.

Answer (score -1):

You assign a pointer to the same memory area, so the last value entered will be displayed.

MT is the 501 bytes of memory reserved, you put user-entered value there, then assign MT's address to the hashTable[i]. Then you put a new value into the same 501 bytes overwriting previous one.

For example, assume that MT[501] has the starting physical address 1000, so each hashTable element will be equal to 1000 and point tot the same memory. That's why you have the same value printed.

Also, since you declared the variable as "auto" it will be allocated on the stack. After the end of the block execution, stack pointer will be adjusted, so this memory could be reused on the next allocation. You do not have any other allocations between end of the block and your print, that's wny it was not overwritten. Otherwise, it will be overwritten by the next memory allocation.

Comment: Nope. Not correct. Anything could be stored there 'cause the variable went out of scope.

Comment: You rewrote the entire answer!

Comment: Added some explanations

Comment: Let me explain it further. The original question was "Why the last value "c" overwrite hashTable[0] and hashTable[1]." It is because the same pointer assigns to the all hashTable elements. This was my answer and it's, for sure correct. Each time SP moves allocating the same addresses and the same starting address assigns then to the hashTable[i]. Of course, it's a mistake to use "auto" variables after the end of the block, so I added this explanation later, altough TS didn't ask about that.